# Fractional parts of the decimal number don't get updated in CRUD

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am creating crud using C# ASP.Net to update the database(including a salary column type=decimal).
In the View, for the input, I have set the type to number and value to the current data, and in the Model and Controller, I've set the data type to decimal. But in the browser, I can not update the fractional part.
Ex: if the current salary is 67.25 and I want to change it to 67.15 I receive this error: Enter a valid value, nearest values 66.25, 68.25.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Help us reproduce your issue so we can figure out what might be wrong.  Maybe provide a minimal reproducible example?

Comment: did you try to update it to 66.25? does that work?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen Yes. It does accept any number as long as the fractional part stays the same.

Comment: I'm guessing you have a `step=1` attribute on the input (or a similar property value on the control). That error looks like an HTML5 validation error message. Use `step="any"` for floats

Comment: @DStanley  I added step="any" and it works, Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Is it a numeric spinner control? The default step is `1` for spinners. Try setting `step` to `0.01` or using a textbox.